# nil value in nested GCD blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I have a collection view that needs to display a collection of images whose files are saved on the device.  They are all 600x600 pixels so I thought it would be better to create the UIImage asynchronously on a background thread and then set the `image` property of my `UIImageView` on the main thread.  Below is where I do this in my `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wo-%@", template.fileName];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (image == nil)
            {
                self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                NSLog(@"image named: %@ in nil!", imageName);
            }
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });

    return cell;
```

Every once in a while `image` will be `nil` for one of the cells.  It isn't reproducible and it's not always the same cell/image name.  I was wondering if this has anything to do with using the `UIImage imageNamed:` method or am I using GCD incorrectly?  I'm interested in why `image` will be `nil` every once in a while and not necessarily alternative ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: use `__block` keyword

Comment: you can use `SDWebimage` library to load Image from link anynchorsly

Comment: @Dhiru, could you explain why?

Comment: its nil because maybe the image has not finished downloaded yet and you are already calling it?